# dynamic insertion with xml or stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have 20 record group that i need to batch insert them all in one connection so there is two solution (XML or stored procedure). this operation frequently executed so i need fast performance and least overhead

1) I think XML is performs slower but we can freely specify how many record we need to insert as a batch by producing the appropriate XML, I don't know the values of each field in a record, there maybe characters that malformed our XML like using " or filed tags in values so how should i prevent this behavior ?

2) using stored procedure is faster but i need to define all input parameters which is boring task and if i need to increase or decrease the number of records inserted in a batch then i need to change the SP

so which solution is better in my environment with respect to my constrains

Comment: What **version** and edition of SQL Server ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML is likely the better choice, however there are other options

If you're using SQL Server 2008 you can use [Table Valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) instead.

Starting with .NET 2.0 you had the option to use the [SQLBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

If you're using oracle you can pass a [user defined type](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ORACLE_UDT.aspx) but I'm not sure what versions of ODP and Oracle that works with.

Note these are all .NET samples. I don't know that this will work for you. It would probably help if you include the database and version and client technology that you're using.